# Eureka Forms Library responding to a row's textfield finishing editing?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, eureka-forms

We are evaluating Eureka Forms, and have created a simple form with a couple FieldRows.  I see how you can get all the values out of a form, and how you can respond when any row is changed at all using onChange() (on a character by character basis) but it is not obvious to me how one responds to a field's editing finishing completely, rather than as each character is typed.

In a normal textfield, we could set the view controller or the cell of a tableview to be the textfield's delegate and respond to textField:didFinishEditing: and handle it there.

How does one do that with a Eureka Forms field row?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the onCellUnHighlight callback, just like the onChange.
The OnCellUnHighlight gets called when the row resigns firstResponder which is when you stop editing.

Note: Because of the default implementation you may have to define onCellHighlight as well because it will override your onCellUnHighlight if you do not.

Comment: Seems to work, though I did need to implement onCellHighlight as well, as you suggested.  I just added an empty implementation, so I am not sure if there I should do there, but it seems to do what I want at the moment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

just to add to the answer here, I ended up using

```
        .onCellHighlightChanged({ (cell, row) in
            if row.isHighlighted == false {
                self.updateUser()
            }
        })
```

and then just checking if the cell isHighlighted or not.

This was using Eureka 4.0